# Restore admin access to gerrit

Tags: openid, gerrit

I have gerrit server with H2DB and google openId access. Google disabled their openId service and now I can't auth on my gerrit's web ui.

1) How can I restore access to my gerrit web ui?

2) Is that possible to make user list with permissions on gerrit server and access via login/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ask only one question.

You should be able to [configure authentication](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#auth) to allow you to log in as any account:

```
[auth]
type = DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT
```

in `etc/gerrit.config`.

This way, I expect that you can then add accounts that existed before to the *Administrator* group.